# Moving from a VPS host to EC2 with as little downtime as possible

Tags: amazon-ec2, vps, ruby-on-rails

We have a rather large server stack (more than 30 machines), and we can't go on using our current VPS provider. we must move, and Amazon's EC2 seems to be our solution.

We use rails, mysql, mongo, redis and other stuff, and we need to move these with as little downtime and with no data loss.

Has anyone here done such a task? anyone with tips on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

So what I'd do, is upload a copy of all the static files, to EC2. Set up the server-side settings in rails, mongo, sql, etc. If you've got databases that change really often, edit the web pages and scripts to READ from the old servers and WRITE to the new ones. Copy all remaining records with the export function. When the files and things are just how you like it, you can change over the DNS settings.

Answer (score 0):

I would shift all persistence first, so all data copied to AWS database instances and they become the working DB instances with your apps staying where they are. Obviously, triple check the backup and retrieval of the DBs before moving on.

If the separation between the apps and data is clean enough, the rest is easier. I found a good Amazon consultant in the states, I can give you his email if you like, saved me a lot of money in the long run.